# What actually JavaScript does here

Tags: javascript, html

Sample:

```js
document.getElementById('p').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.textContent = 'Hello';
});
```

```html
<p id="p">Hello</p>
```

It might seem clear, but I wonder what really happens when you click on the element:

- JavaScript removes the element default text content and set it as `Hello`.
- It replaces the old `Hello` with the new `Hello`.
- It does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Lol.  It's nothing special.

Comment: it will reset `textContent` of `p` when it is clicked.

Comment: `this` is a dynamic keyword refering to whatever is the scope when a function is triggered. You click the `<p>`, the scope is that HTMLElement, so the function replaces the element's textContent. There is nothing special going on here, and many google search terms could have been used to find this out. Of course, `thing.onclick = function...` is pretty much deprecated JS at this point, it uses the antiquated JavaScript 1 "on..." handler system, and is simply available in modern JS for legacy compatibilty reasons. The proper way to do even handling is with `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Jamen: the question might seem stupid, but it really makes my mind busy how JavaScript works in such cases.

Comment: @Hermes then read the ECMAScript specification ([ES5 here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)) instead of asking questions that are entailed by the spec. It's a good read, and you learn a lot.

Comment: For this particular example, all three are valid descriptions. When you set up the `textContent` property you are replacing text (which means removing text) and it certainly doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: JavaScript is not doing anything particular here. It's the DOM methods and properties that are calling the callback on click, and modifying the DOM via the `textContent` property of the element. By the way, it would be preferable to use `addEventListener` here instead of assigning to the `onclick` property.

Comment: @torazaburo: Thanks for the pointer! I just learned about `addEventListener` and modified my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It replaces the old hello with the new hello.

In detail, the code replaces the ***text*** contents of the element with `id` = `p` with the specified text. Note that is text only -- if you want to inject HTML code, you would use `innerHTML` instead.

You can see that most clearly if you substitute the replacement text with something else, such as:

```
document.getElementById('p').onclick = function() {
  this.textContent = 'Bob';
};
```

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating what happens:

https://jsfiddle.net/3smrzxw5/

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I believe they're asking if the code is optimized to essentially do nothing, or is it wasting CPU cycles

Answer (score 0):

`textContent` is an API in the DOM. In your example, it will replace whatever text is assigned to `textContent` inside the onclick function.

If the question is about what the parser actually does, that'll depend on the implementation. Like for a performance improvement, the parser may not replace the value if the content is the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this code you can understand it :

```
<p id="p">Hello</p>
document.getElementById('p').onclick = function() {
  this.textContent = 'hii';
};
```

actually it replaces the content when you click on the text.